# checkboxes for all elements in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to display a checkbox for all elements in a model called MyModel. Here is what I wrote:

```
<%=  MyModel.all.each do |c| %>
    <%= check_box_tag(:id) %>
    <%= label_tag(:name, c[:name]) %><br>
<% end %>
```

It does show the checkboxes as expected but at the end, I also get a list of the model content as shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv2hj.png).

Actually, it seems to be related to `<%=  MyModel.all.each do |c| %>` because just printing out simple text still prints the whole model table content at the end:

```
<%=  MyModel.all.each do |c| %>
    toto<br>
<% end %>
```

shows this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh7FK.png)

Any idea how to get rid of this list at the end?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%-  MyModel.all.each do |c| %>
    <%= check_box_tag(:id) %>
    <%= label_tag(:name, c[:name]) %><br>
<% end %>
```

`-` - evaluates code.

`=` - evaluates code and outputs.

Comment: Thanks Andrey! That fixed it :)